# Opening a context menu without registering the view

Tags: android, view, contextmenu

How can I open a context menu for a view without registering it using `registerForContextMenu()`?

My activity overrides `onTouchEvent` to detect motion, and if I use `registerForContextMenu()` it stops working. I'm detecting a long press, so I'd like to forward that request to a method that would build the menu for me, but don't know if it can work that way.

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to find a solution? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [View.setOnCreateContextMenuListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnCreateContextMenuListener(android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener)) to manually bind your activity as the context menu provider for a view at layout initialization time, and then call [View.showContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#showContextMenu%28%29) on the view once you detect a long press to bring up the menu.  It should call through to your `onCreateContextMenu` call just as if you'd registered it the normal way.

EDIT: Okay, this has the same effect of overriding the touch event listener for the view.  Given that, the only solution I can think of is to create a hidden view and register to be *that* view's context menu provider, and then ask it to show a context menu as above when a long touch on the real/visible view is seen.

Comment: Tried it, it gives me same result as `registerForContextMenu()`, which is it breaks the motion detection. So the event must be consumed higher up in the chain than I want.

Comment: Hmm, that's too bad.  Horrible-hackery option added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

My onTouchEvent have the followed lines. It's not beautiful, but it's working.

```
private void onLongPressed(View view) {
    registerForContextMenu(view);
    view.getParent().showContextMenuForChild(view);
    unregisterForContextMenu(view);
}
```

The onLongPressed-function is calling, if I detect a long press in my one onTouchListener.